# Is there any compelling reason to not be able to use equal operator(==) for default(T) in C#

Tags: c#, generics

The equal operator and default value of generic type are two handy feature in C#. But we can't easily use them seamlessly. For example, I expect the following code can compile,

```
public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(T subject){
        return subject == default(T);
    }
```

Unfortunately, it'll fail, though there's an counter-intuitive alternative,

```
public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(T subject){
        return object.Equals(subject, default(T));
    }
```

So my question is why C# disallows the first code snippet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it does not work is that the built-in reference equality operator cannot be applied to value types.

Let's take step back and note that [System.Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not, in fact, define an equality operator `==`. The C# language defines a built-in reference equality operator with the signature (see section 7.6.10 of the C# 5 specification):

```
bool operator ==(object x, object y);
```

However, there two rules about when it can be applied:

> The predefined reference type equality operators require one of the following:
>
> > - Both operands are a value of a type known to be a reference-type or the literal null. Furthermore, an explicit reference conversion (§6.2.4) exists from the type of either operand to the type of the other operand.
> > - One operand is a value of type T where T is a type-parameter and the other operand is the literal null. Furthermore T does not have the value type constraint.

The spec then notes that this means that it is an error to apply the operator to two value types unless the type explicitly defines an equality operator. Since you have no constraints, value types are allowed and neither of the operands is null. Therefore, the built-in equality operator cannot be applied and an error is produced.

To remedy this, you could constrain `T` be a reference type:

```
public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(T subject) where T : class {
    return subject == default(T);
}
```

However you do need to be aware that the above is always a reference comparison. The compiler will only invoke the `==` operator on the most specific applicable type at compile time, which in this case is `object`.

A better alternative is to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to prevent boxing of value types:

```
public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(T subject) {
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(subject, default(T));
}
```

I suppose you could ask why C# was not designed to have a default equality operator that can be applied to value types without boxing. I do not know the full reason, but I suspect that it might be more confusing than it is now to determine which methods you are calling in which situations. I think it would be undesirable if in normal methods the overloaded operator was called but in generic methods another mechanism was used. Although you can argue that can happen now with reference types.

Comment: So the C# team leave this to the programmer to warn them to consider the boxing and unboxing.

Comment: @ivenxu No the compiler is not going to warn you about boxing here or anywhere else. It is something you need to be aware of when writing perf sensitive generic code.

Comment: Can the behavior of the C# compiler really be accurately described as behaving as though it has an `==` overload as described, or would it be more accurate to say that it behaves as though the `==` token will invoke an overloaded equality-test operator if one exists, and will otherwise behave as a reference-equality operator in cases where it can do so?  I don't think there are any other situations where parameters of type `object` would have their overload resolution work the way `==` does.

Comment: @supercat That might be a more accurate way to describe it overall. I was trying to describe what happens when the compile-time types are involved are known to be reference types where the behavior isn't really distinguishable. I think the compiler must have something more like the logic you describe internally because this is quite specific to `==`.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, the compiler is complaining because T could be anything: reference types or struct.

Hence if you make it explicit with constraint:

```
public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(T subject) where T : class{
return subject == default(T);
}
```

It'll not complain anymore. Because now, the compiler knows, it's always going to be reference types.

Apparently, for the second one.

```
public static bool EqualsDefault<T>(T subject){
    return object.Equals(subject, default(T));
}
```

It works because, all the pre-defined or user-defined types in .net directly or indirectly inherit from object and object implements Equals method.